# SQL Union do not show same emails, but other can be same

Tags: php, sql, union

I have this code:

```
$prikaz = mysql_query("select t.*
from (
      SELECT mesta_email, mesta_meno, mesto
      FROM mesta2014
      UNION
      SELECT mesta_email, mesta_meno, mesto
      FROM mesta2015
)
t left join mesta3 t3 on t.mesta_email = t3.mesta_email                      
where t3.mesta_email is null
")
```

I need to not show the same emails in results, even though the other columns (`mesta_meno` and `mesto`) are different. So there could be two rows with different information except for mesta_email = in result there has to be only one result. Can you help me please with solving this?

Comment: Does it matter which values of mesta_meno and mesto you want returned?  Can it be any of the rows' values?

Comment: The approach you would take will vary depending on if you wanted the most recent or least recent data (mesta_meno, mesto) per email, or don't care which year's data you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values of `mesta_meno` and `mesto` do not matter, then do the following:

```
$prikaz = mysql_query("select t.mesta_email, min(t.mesta_meno) as mesta_meno, min(t.mesto) as mesto
from (
      SELECT mesta_email, mesta_meno, mesto
      FROM mesta2014
      UNION
      SELECT mesta_email, mesta_meno, mesto
      FROM mesta2015
)
t left join mesta3 t3 on t.mesta_email = t3.mesta_email
where t3.mesta_email is null
group by t.mesta_email
")
```